# Rails3 model gets stuck when using paperclip has_attached_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

When I try to save an unvalid model object I don'tget an error message but my app gets stuck, I expect the test to fail not to get stuck. (when using with valid attributes, i.e. specifying an image file everything works as expected an the object is valid.)

I found out that it's becasue of paperclip when using has_attached_file :image 
any ideas why it happens?

**models/user_image.rb**

```
 has_attached_file :image  
 :image_content_type, :presence => true
 validate :valid_res        

 validates_attachment_content_type
 :image,    :content_type =>
 ['image/jpeg','image/jpg','[image/jpeg]',
 '[image/png]', 'image/png'] ...
```

**user_image_spec.rb**

```
describe UserImage do

before(:each) do
  @user_image = UserImage.new(
  :uid => "1234abca"
  )
end

it "is valid with valid attributes" do
  @user_image.should be_valid
end
```

Update: I was using the paperclip plugin, so I removed it and installed the gem. still getting the same result, am i suppose to do something after installing the gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what does this line means:

```
:image_content_type, :presence => true
```

I think this one causes your troubles

Comment: I removed it still gets stuck.

Comment: also what is `validate :valid_res`?

Comment: Yea that was it, thats a validation method that I have created to validate the image resolution. I thought that it will just fail if there's no image, thanks for the help! now i know what to fix.

Answer (score 0):

To validate PaperClip image just add:

```
validates :image, :attachment_presence => true
```